# Webcam doesn't work in Hydro

Tags: ros, webcam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As i  used the
`$ roslaunch rbx1_vision uvc_cam.launch device:=/dev/video0`
in the book *ros-by-example* for hydro , i find the output like this :

```
exbot@ubuntu:~/catkin_ws$  roslaunch rbx1_vision uvc_cam.launch device:=/dev/video0
... logging to /home/exbot/.ros/log/bda49708-6edb-11e4-b665-44334c160d17/roslaunch-ubuntu-4099.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://ubuntu:34919/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion
 * /uvc_cam_node/device
 * /uvc_cam_node/exposure
 * /uvc_cam_node/frame_rate
 * /uvc_cam_node/gain
 * /uvc_cam_node/height
 * /uvc_cam_node/width

NODES
  /
    uvc_cam_node (uvc_cam/uvc_cam_node)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[uvc_cam_node-1]: started with pid [4117]
[ INFO] [1416292448.855562602]: opening uvc_cam at 320x240, 20.000000 fps
opening /dev/video0
capabilities 84000001
pixfmt 0 = 'YUYV' desc = 'YUV 4:2:2 (YUYV)'
  discrete: 640x480:   1/30 1/30 
  discrete: 320x240:   1/30 1/30 
camera formats supported
format 0 = 'YUYV' desc = 'YUV 4:2:2 (YUYV)'
  discrete: 640x480:   1/30 1/30 
  discrete: 320x240:   1/30 1/30 
[ WARN] [1416292448.856026405]: Reconfigure callback failed with exception couldn't set format:
```

and  when  i  used :

```
$ rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/rgb/image_color
```

it only show a blank window;

why ??

i can see the picture form my webcam from cheese,  but cant use it in ROS hydro

thinks a lot !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197643/webcam-doesn%27t-work-in-hydro/) by [kdsong](https://answers.ros.org/users/20846/kdsong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2014-11-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not a direct answer to your question, but I strngly suggest you to post your question on his group: https://groups.google.com/d/forum/ros-by-example
I can tell you, Patrick is very fast about answering questions. Everytime I asked a question on his group he was really fast and precise giving me a lot of useful informations.

Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) with karma: 893 on 2014-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0